# how to sum two aggregate functions

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am building a report in visual Studio and have various calculations for things like total etc.

I am now trying to find the percentage of two totals but I am struggling as it won't allow me to use 2 aggregate functions in my one expression.

The functions I have are:

```
=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Services")
```

AND

```
=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Services")
```

They are the same function but act for 2 different totals so in order to find out the percentage I have to divide both these functions by each other see below:-

```
=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Services")/=Sum(Fields! Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Services")
```

can anyone suggest a better way to do this?

Many thanks,

Comment: Use a [LookUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) function over the different datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your response Preet.  I'm not totally sure how I would do a Lookup function on these values could you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Val function

Simply try this

```
=Val(Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Services"))/Val(Sum(Fields! Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Services"))
```

Comment: Thanks ling.s that almost gets me where I need to be but I was execting an answer of 1 when I used your script as they contain the same total values in this aspect but instead got the value of the totals?  Example both totals are 1391 and divided by each other I was expecting a value of 1 but I got 1391?  any further advice?

Comment: okay the value of Quantity.Value, "AccruedHours" = 535 and the value of Quantity.Value, "Services" = 856 with my original sum aggregate bring a total of 1391.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end.

The way I did it was using the below code to reference the exact text boxes rather than trying to do seperate aggregate functions.  This way I just had to do a divide on the two totals.

See below code:-

```
=(ReportItems!textbox20.Value) / 
(ReportItems!textbox22.Value)
```

Thanks anyway for the suggestions to the original question.